# Replace string with sed

Tags: regex, string, sed, replace

File Content:

```
world-123.hello-abcd
world-124.good
world-125.bye-abcd
world-126.bye
```

Expected result:

```
world-123.hello
world-124.good
world-125.bye
world-126.bye
```

Command I'm trying to fix:

```
cat file | sed 's:\..*-.*::'
```

Result I get:

```
world-123
world-124.good
world-125
world-126.bye
```

How do I fix missing content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
sed 's:-[^.-]*$::' file
```

The `-[^.-]*$` pattern matches a `-` and then any 0 or more chars other than `.` and `-` till the end of the string.

See the [online `sed` demo](https://ideone.com/rFaMnx).